# How to use fields and variables to save data permanently in Google Actions with Dialogflow?

Tags: arrays, node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I'm trying to build up a timetable-Google-Action. The Action is supposed to tell all the subjects of a certain day when calling.
The Problem is, how do I save the data permanently on my device to access the data at any time?

I tried to declare fields in the fulfillment NODE.JS-File, but that did not worked at all. (I realised that it was a really stupid idea, as the code does not work as a 'programm', so there is no compiled stuff running in the background).
The next thing I tried was the code snippet on the Google-Developer website (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data#df_nodejs) -> Snippet 1

I don't have any further knowledge of Java-Script or Node.JS or Google Actions in Dialogflow, but my teacher told us to develop an application without giving any information about that topic.

You can see my Fulfillment Code in Snippet 2

Snippet 1

```
function simpleResponse(conv) {
  conv.user.storage.count = 1;
  conv.ask('When is your birthday?');
}
```

Snippet 2

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

 /*  FUNCTIONS  */ 
  function getSubjects(agent) {
    const date = agent.parameters.date;
    const dateIso = new Date(date);
    const weekDayInt = dateIso.getDay();
    var dayString = '';
    switch (weekDayInt){
      case 0: dayString='Sonntag'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.sun.join(' ');
      break;
      case 1: dayString='Montag'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.mon.join(' ');
      break;
      case 2: dayString='Dienstag'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.tue.join(' ');
      break;
      case 3: dayString='Mittwoch'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.wed.join(' ');
      break;
      case 4: dayString='Donnerstag'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.thu.join(' ');
      break;
      case 5: dayString='Freitag'; 
        var output = agent.user.storage.fri.join(' ');
      break;
      case 6: dayString='Samstag'; 
       var output = agent.user.storage.sat.join(' ');
      break;
    }
    agent.add(`This message is from Dialogflow's Cloud Functions for Firebase editor!`);
      agent.add(new Card({
        title:`Dein Stundenplan für `+dayString+`:`,
          //imageUrl: 'https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png',
          text: 'Du hast heute'+output+' .',
          buttonText: 'This is a button',
          buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
      })
    );
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Stundenplan für heute`));
      agent.add(new Suggestion(`Stundenplan für morgen`));
  }

  function setSubject(agent){
    const subject = agent.parameters.subject;
    const date = agent.context.get('date');
    const dateIso = new Date(date);
    const weekDayInt = dateIso.getDay();
    var dayString = '';
    switch (weekDayInt){
      case 0: dayString='Sonntag';
        agent.user.storage.sun.push(subject);
        break;
      case 1: dayString='Montag';
        agent.user.storage.mon.push(subject);
        break;
      case 2: dayString='Dienstag';
        agent.user.storage.tue.push(subject);
        break;
      case 3: dayString='Mittwoch';
        agent.user.storage.wed.push(subject);
        break;
      case 4: dayString='Donnerstag';
        agent.user.storage.thu.push(subject);
        break;
      case 5: dayString='Freitag';
        agent.user.storage.fri.push(subject);
        break;
      case 6: dayString='Samstag';
        agent.user.storage.sat.push(subject);
        break;
    }
  }
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Stundenplan', getSubjects);
  intentMap.set('WhichSubject', setSubject);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

/////
UPDATE
/////

I now tried your code, but it did not functioned at all. Google interpretes the day wrong whithout any changes of the code (I'm a bit confused) and the string (whith the subjects) can't be saved neither.

It would be great if you'll take a loook at my new fulfillment code again and tell me what is wrong.

Snippet 3

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow, BasicCard, Suggestions} = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('GetTimeTable', (conv, {date}) => {
  const dateIso = new Date(date);
  const weekDayInt = dateIso.getDay();
  let dayString = '';
  let output = '';
  switch (weekDayInt) {
    case 0:
      dayString = 'Sonntag';
      output = conv.user.storage.sun;
      break;
    case 1:
        dayString='Montag'; 
        output = conv.user.storage.mon;
      break;
    case 2:
      dayString='Dienstag'; 
      output = conv.user.storage.tue;
      break;
    case 3:
      dayString='Mittwoch'; 
      output = conv.user.storage.wed;
      break;
    case 4:
      dayString='Donnerstag'; 
      output = conv.user.storage.thu;
      break;
    case 5:
      dayString='Freitag'; 
      output = conv.user.storage.fri;
      break;
    case 6:
      dayString='Samstag'; 
      output = conv.user.storage.sat;
      break;
  }
  conv.ask(`Du hast am ${dayString} ${output}`);
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    title: `Dein Studenplan für ${dayString}:`,
    text: `Du hast ${dayString}  ${output}.`,
  }));
});


app.intent('WhichSubject', (conv, {date, subject}) => {    
  const dateIso = new Date(date);
  const weekDayInt = dateIso.getDay();
  let dayString = '';
  //conv.user.storage.sun = 'Deutsch';

  switch (weekDayInt){
    case 0:
      dayString='Sonntag';
      conv.user.storage.sun = ''+subject;
      break;
    case 1:
      dayString='Montag';
      conv.user.storage.mon = ''+subject;
      break;
    case 2:
      dayString='Dienstag';
      conv.user.storage.tue = subject;
      break;
    case 3:
      dayString='Mittwoch';
      conv.user.storage.wed = subject;
      break;
    case 4:
      dayString='Donnerstag';
      conv.user.storage.thu = subject;
      break;
    case 5:
      dayString='Freitag';
      conv.user.storage.fri = subject;
      break;
    case 6:
      dayString='Samstag';
      conv.user.storage.sat = subject;
      break;
  }
  conv.ask(`Am ${dayString} das Fach ${subject}.`);
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    title: `Neu gespeichert:`,
    text: `Am ${dayString} das Fach ${subject}.`,
  }));

});

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that in the first snippet it assumes the `actions-on-google` library instead of the `dialogflow-fulfillment` library.

The `userStorage` feature is only available for Actions on Google, so you would need to transition all of your code to use `actions-on-google` instead of `dialogflow-fulfillment`.

Here's a quick example of how you could adjust your code to use the library. This is not a complete set of changes, but should help you get started.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {dialogflow, BasicCard, Suggestions} = require('actions-on-google');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

const app = dialogflow();

app.intent('Stundenplan', (conv, {date}) => {
  const dateIso = new Date(date);
  const weekDayInt = dateIso.getDay();
  let dayString = '';
  let output = '';
  switch (weekDayInt) {
    case 0:
      dayStrin = 'Sonntag';
      output = conv.user.storage.sun.join(' ');
      break;
    // ...
  }
  conv.ask('This message is from the Dialogflow Cloud Function for Firebase editor');
  conv.ask(new BasicCard({
    title: `Dein Studenplan für ${dayString}:`,
    text: `Du hast heute ${output}.`,
    buttonText: 'This is a button',
    buttonUrl: 'https://assistant.google.com/'
  }));
  conv.ask(new Suggestions('Stundenplan für heute', 'Stundenplan für morgen'))
})

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That really helped me!